# Unable to create one-way EGDB --> EGDB replica

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.6, replication, error-000582

I have an Enterprise geodatabase with 30 feature datasets, each containing multiple feature classes.  Both parent and child are Oracle databases.  I've successfully created replicas for 28 of those datasets.  However, I am now not able to create any new replicas.  I am creating the replicas via a Python script that runs the arcpy.CreateReplica_management command using the following parameters:

```
arcpy.CreateReplica_management(fds,"ONE_WAY_REPLICA",replica,repname,"SIMPLE","PARENT_DATA_SENDER","DO_NOT_ADD","DO_NOT_REUSE","DO_NOT_GET_RELATED",None,"ARCHIVING")
```

The script runs for only a couple minutes before throwing an exception with the generic error 000582.

The ReplicaLog.dat file gives the following:

ReplicaMsg time='9/23/2020 10:09:27 AM' type='LOG_MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR' code='90012' elapsed='162.771000 seconds' method='GeoDBReplication::CreateChildReplicaEx' objectClassName='' replicaName='GEODATA.test'> The item was not found.</ReplicaMsg

I suspect that script is unable to register the replica on the parent database, but not sure how to troubleshoot or resolve the issue.

A few things I've tried are:

- I did unregister (on parent and child) one of the previously created repliacas, and attempted to recreate, but this produced the same errors as above.
- I confirmed that the child database can accept replicas from other Enterprise geodatabases, so I don't think there is an issue with the child database.
- I've attempted to look for orphaned replicas using the guidance in https://community.esri.com/thread/114158.  However, the sde.versions table does not list any of the existing replicas.  I presume this is because my replicas are setup using archiving for tracking changes, but not certain.

Does anybody know how to resolve the above described situation?

Comment: It's only named "sde.sde_versions" in non-Oracle databases; the "SDE.sde_" tables are just "SDE." in Oracle. Trouble-shooting has an intrinsic back-and-forth that is difficult to achieve in GIS SE. Tech Support is really your best option when you need to start removing rows from the enterprise registry.

Comment: @vince I've modified the section of my post related to the sde.versions table to point out that the table does not include any of my replicas.  I assume this is because my replicas are created using archiving to track changes, but not certain about that.

Comment: Since you are erroring out while using scripting to create the replicas, I suggest troubleshooting by first manually creating the replicas for fds 29 and 30 because we know the first 28 work correctly.

Comment: Instead of using Python script, use the manual creation with the distributed toolbar to create the replica. Also, is the issue specifically with the creation of one-way replica? https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/production-mapping-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-distributed-geodatabase-toolset.htm